# dotnet build throwing nullreference exception

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a project that builds and runs fine locally. However, it is failing to build when I push it up to my server (Windows Server 2012 R2). It does not give me any detail as to why it is failing. Even when I add the verbose flag.

> PS C:\projectroot> dotnet -v build
>
> Telemetry is: Enabled
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I don't see anything in the event logs. Is there anywhere else I can look for error info to get this narrowed down? Any other ideas?

I suspect it may be some missing dependency since it works locally, but don't know where to look next to figure it out.

Here's a copy of my project.json. I tried several combinations of things before arriving at the workaround of building the projects individually.

```
{
"webroot": "wwwroot",
"userSecretsId": "secret",
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",
    "AutoMapper": "4.1.1",
    "MyApp.Domain": "1.0.0-*",
    "MyApp.Configuration": "1.0.0-*",
    "MyApp.Data": "1.0.0-*",
    "MyApp.Data.EF6": "1.0.0-*",
    "MyApp.Services": "1.0.0-*",
    "MyApp.Services.ETL": "1.0.0-*",
    "Scrutor": "1.3.1",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.0",
    "HtmlSanitizer": "3.2.105",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core": "2.2.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
        "type": "build",
        "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
        "type": "build",
        "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
    }
},
"tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
},
"frameworks": {
    "net461": {
    }
},
"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
        "wwwroot",
        "Views",
        "Areas/**/Views/**/*.cshtml",
        "web.config",
        "config.json",
        "logs",
        "Aspose.Pdf.lic"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "prepublish": [
        "npm install",
        "bower install",
        "gulp clean",
        "gulp min"
    ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
},
"buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "compile": {
        "exclude": [
            "wwwroot",
            "node_modules",
            "bower_components"
        ]
    }
},
"runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
        "System.GC.Server": true
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you build any other projects, e.g. any hello world on your server? Can you post the full output you are getting? Can you post contents of your project.json?

Comment: Yes. I can build a project created with dotnet new. I actually made some progress. I discovered that if I build all of the projects individually, in order of dependency then it will succeed. So the error seems to have to something to do with referencing a project that has not yet been built. So I have a workaround for now, but this seems like a bug to me. The above is the full output. That is what is makes it so difficult to troubleshoot. Not even a stack trace to go on. I can post the project.json when back at my computer if you still think it relevant.

Comment: What .Net Core stuff do you have installed on your server? Runtime/SDK etc. Can you clarify what's your solution structure, so I could replicate the issue on my machine.

Comment: I installed the VS Update 3 and Core 1.0.1 listed here - https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows. I added a copy of my current project.json above. From there you can see that the web project references several other projects (with the MyApp prefix). Thanks for the help. I do want to clarify that the workaround of building the projects individually is working for me at the moment. I just have them all scripted to build in the correct order. So this is not urgent at this point. Though I am curious what the cause is, or if it's a bug worth reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Did you attempt to clean the project before running? Because the "cached" files when building in your own laptop/workstation might have been reused on the server.

In your project.json,

I noticed that you're using the 461 framework. Not sure if .NET Core uses that too because I've always been using this

```
 "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
}
```

Comment: I did not clean. Is there an equivalent of "dotnet clean"? Or are you suggesting that I manually go through and try to remove stuff?

Comment: The project source is being pulled down to the server straight from source control. So none of the non-external dependencies should be pre-built or cached. I am also running a "dotnet restore" prior to the build to get the external dependencies as well.

Targeting framework 4.6.1 is intentional. Are you suggesting the way I'm referencing it might be incorrect?

Comment: If the framework reference were incorrect I'd expect that it wouldn't build or run at all. Even locally.